# How to mock tRPC procedures with vitest and vitest-mock-extended on client side

Tags: typescript, vitest, trpc.io

I'm trying to mock tRPC procedures so I don't need to run the tRPC backend application to run frontend unit tests. I've tried to use [`vitest-mock-extended`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vitest-mock-extended)'s `mock` and `mockDeep` functions. The trpc client still tries to make a request **over the network**, and get's a connection refused error. `vitest-mock-extended` has worked for the trpc backend application.

### Works with normal classes

```js
// When userService doesn't use tRPC, it's easy to mock.
const userService = mock<UserService>();
// Works. Typescript suggests all the test functions
userService.createUser.mockResolvedValueOnce({"name": "Fake test user"});
```

### Doesn't work with tRPC procedures

```
// When using tRPC, typescript doesn't find mockResolvedValueOnce
const userService = mock<typeof context.services.trpcClient.userService>();
// Doesn't work. only `query` or `mutation` is shown.
userService.createUser.mutation.mockResolvedValueOnce({"name": "Fake test user"});
userService.getUser.query.mockResolvedValueOnce({"name": "Fake test user"});
```

I'm using tRPC, typescript, vitest and [vitest-mock-extended](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vitest-mock-extended).

### mockDeep attempt example

```js
const userService = mockDeep<typeof context.services.trpcClient.userService>>();
missionManager.createUser.mutation.mockResolvedValueOnce({...});
missionManager.createUser.query.mockResolvedValueOnce({...});
```

---

Has anyone successfully mocked trpc requests on the client side for e.g. a react/typescript application. Since tests are run by vitest, this is actually a Node/jsdom environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found [msw-trpc](https://github.com/maloguertin/msw-trpc) which will allow you to use msw in a tRPC type-safe way.

It works if you only use [HTTPLink](https://trpc.io/docs/client/links/httpLink). Unfortunately, it doesn't support WebSockets (I use WsLink with tRPC in 1 project) so I created a [Github issue](https://github.com/maloguertin/msw-trpc/issues/19). Alternatively, you could try combining [`mock-socket`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-socket) and a wrapper class to use your tRPC AppRouter type.

They haven't documented how to use it in vitest, so here's how I do it. Install dependencies: `pnpm add -D vitest vitest-mock-extended msw msw-trpc`.

### How to use in tests

```js
import { AppRouter } from "../trpc/appRouter";
import { setupServer } from "msw/node";
import { createTRPCMsw } from "msw-trpc";
import { beforeEach, describe, it, vi } from "vitest";
import { mockDeep } from 'vitest-mock-extended';
import { trpcClient } from "./trpcClient";

// You probably want to put this in a `setupTests.ts` so it runs in all tests.
vi.mock("./trpcClient", () => {
  return {
    trpcClient: mockDeep(),
  };
});

export const trpcMsw = createTRPCMsw<AppRouter>();
// You can create the responses, and change it for each test in vitest/jest.
const server = setupServer();
// Put any handlers you want to work for all tests.

describe("Example class", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    server.resetHandlers(); // resets to the original handlers, which I did not set.
  });

  it("parses and loads products json into local SQLite database", async () => {
    server.use(
      trpcMsw.product.getProduct.query(async (req, res, ctx) => {
        // body is deprecated in msw, but the alternative req.json() is not typed...
        // const body = await req.json();
        // Do something with body.
        const body = req.body;
        return res(ctx.status(200), ctx.data(undefined));
      })
    );

    // Run some code, then run assertions.
  });

  // more tests...
});
```

Comment: Hi. What is mockDeep and whey did you assign it to trpcClient while mocking it instead of trpcMsw? Do you know how we can achieve this setup using jest?